# Show that number of units of $2^{2^n}+1$ is always $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

> Given that $n$ is a natural number such that $n\geq2$, show that number of units of $x=2^{2^n}+1$ is always $7$

For $n=2$ we have $x=17$. For $n=3$ we have $x=257$

We can show that the number of units of $2^{2^n}$ is always $6$ too!

I don't know how can I start my proof! 
I don't know how can I start my proof !

Comment: A very dull hint: try induction.

Comment: I forgot about induction ! Thank you

Comment: But I don't know the formula of numbers wich has 7 as number of units !

Comment: Are you sure this is true? I think that if $n$ is divisible by $10$ then $2^{2^n}+1$ ends with $3$.

Comment: @barakmanos 2^(2^10)+1=179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137217

Comment: What is the number of units of an integer $x$? The cardinality of $(\mathbb Z/x\mathbb Z)^\times$??

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I really don't know i ll be thankful if you told me ! We are just studing mathematical proof ! I think the solution of my level is with induction as said asydot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last digit of $2^{2^2}$ is $6$. And if $n\ge 3$ then 
$$\frac{2^{2^n}}{2^{2^2}}=2^{2^n-4}=2^{4k}=16^k$$
That is,
$$2^{2^n}=2^{2^2}\cdot 16^k$$
Every power of a number that ends with $6$ also ends with $6$, so $2^{2^n}$ can be expressed as the product of two numbers that end with $6$. Thus, $2^{2^n}$ ends with $6$.

Comment: *-* very nice answer ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Modulo $5$: $2^{2^n}=16^{2^{n-2}}\equiv1^{2^{n-2}}=1$;
Modulo $2$: $2^{2^n}\equiv0$
so by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)/common sense we have $2^{2^n}\equiv6\pmod{10}$. Hence $2^{2^n}+1\equiv7\pmod{10}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! But what is the relation between remainder and number of units ?

Comment: @user233658 the remainder *is* the number of units you want.

Comment: @Asydot can you express clearly?

Comment: For a number $x$ we can always express them as $x=a_n10^n+a_{n-1}10^{n-1}+...+a_0$ (all $a_i$ are integers between 0 and 9,$a_n \neq 0$)and as you know $a_0$ is the number of unit of $x$. While notice that $x=10(a_n10^{n-1}+...+a_1)+a_0$, so $a_0$ is also the remainder when you divide $x$ by $10$.

Answer (score 1):

**First, show that this is true for $n=2$:**

$2^{2^2}+1=17$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$2^{2^n}+1=10k+7$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$2^{2^{n+1}}+1=$

$(\color\red{2^{2^n}+1}-1)^2+1=$

$(\color\red{10k+7}-1)^2+1=$

$100k^2+120k+37=$

$10(10k^2+12k+3)+7$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.